# Count number of foreign keys using KEY_COLUMN_USAGE in the information schema

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I have a very large MySQL database and I need to know how many foreign keys does it have. I tried with the command:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'number of foreign keys'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='pubs' 
AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

in a small database (pubs) and it returned the correct number of foreign keys, but I'm not sure if this query is OK in all cases.
Is this query correct? Is there another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have any composite foreign keys, it will count each column separately. Other than that, it seems perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`referential_constraints`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/referential-constraints-table.html) table contains information about foreign keys. So you can simply do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONSTRAINT_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'pubs';
```

Using `COUNT(DISTINCT)` combines multiple columns that are in the same foreign key constraint. If you want to count all the columns separately, use `COUNT(*)` instead.

Comment: How I can specify the database name in this query?

Comment: With `CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want foreign keys, then I think this will work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `number of foreign keys`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'pubs' AND 
      POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT = 1;
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/key-column-usage-table.html), `POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT` is `NULL` for primary key and unique key constraints.  So, it is 1 for the first key column for a foreign key constraint.